LiveKD generates corrupted kernel dump with dummy KD
I am trying to collect live kernel dump with minimal & portable setup for issue diagnosis. The best solution I have found so far is to use the Sysinternals LiveKD utility with the -ml argument, which "generate live dump using native support (Windows 8.1 and above only)" with the undocumented NtSystemDebugControl API.
Running it with WDK kd.exe in cwd goes correctly without issues.
> .\livekd.exe -ml -o test.dmp

LiveKd v5.63 - Execute kd/windbg on a live system
Sysinternals - www.sysinternals.com
Copyright (C) 2000-2020 Mark Russinovich and Ken Johnson

Saving live dump to C:\<path>\test.dmp... done.

> .\kd.exe -z .\test_realkd.dmp
<omitted>
For analysis of this file, run !analyze -v
0: kd>

Since LiveKD does not appear to be using kd.exe according to this SO question, I replaced the WDK kd.exe with a dummy executable that only outputs argv to both stdout and a file.
> .\livekd.exe -ml -o test.dmp

LiveKd v5.63 - Execute kd/windbg on a live system
Sysinternals - www.sysinternals.com
Copyright (C) 2000-2020 Mark Russinovich and Ken Johnson

Saving live dump to C:\<path>\test.dmp... done.
Converting C:\<path>\test.dmp to summary dump format...

An additional line of "converting to summary dump format" is output by LiveKD, although the dummy kd.exe is not executed. The size of the dump looks correct, but loading the dump file into kernel debugger fails with the error below.
> .\kd.exe -z .\test.dmp
<omitted>
Loading Dump File [C:\<path>\test.dmp]
Could not match Dump File signature - invalid file format
Could not open dump file [.\test.dmp], Win32 error 0n87
    "The parameter is incorrect."
Debuggee initialization failed, Win32 error 0n87
The parameter is incorrect.

My question is,

What would LiveKD behave differently despite it not executing kd.exe?
What does "converting to summary dump format" actually do?
How to fix the corrupted dump file and have it loaded into the debugger?

